# Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel

There is a proper way to check if a collection is Empty and update the
 collection with another filter level value condition in order to get a collection not empty ?

here my collection :

```
 $arbitres = $arbitres->reject(function ($arbitre) use ($rencontre) {
                return $arbitre->rencontreOfficiels->contains(function ($rencontreOfficiels) use ($rencontre) {
                    return $rencontreOfficiels->rencontre_id === $rencontre->id;
                });
            })->filter(function($arbitre){

                return $arbitre->level >= 3;

            });
```

If my collection is empty with `$arbitre->level >= 3` i would like to update the value till getting a not empty collection without duplicating the code many times. there is a proper way ?

```
if($arbitres->isEmpty()){
//
}
```

Comment: Update the value to what?

Comment: updating the value to 4 if empty then  5 if empty then  6 .. @ChinLeung

Comment: Please don't repost the same question or use `>` for "text", thank you.